# php mysql delete from database

Tags: php

Hey hello everyone,i have a slight problem with my small delete function in php,below is my code

```
function delete()
    {
    $q = "DELETE FROM example WHERE **author='frank'";**

    $r = mysql_query($q) or die (mysql_error());
    if($r)
    {
        echo 'done';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'not done';
    }
    }
```

Now i don't have any author with that name Frank so that means it is not deleting anything
from the database but still shows that done msg

I am not sure why????can anyone please help me

Comment: Needs more info. What does your example table contain? What data type is the author column?

Comment: `mysql_query()` returns a STATEMENT HANDLE if the query succeeded, or FALSE if there was an error. A query which does nothing is still considered a successful query, so unless your query has a syntax error or some other database error occurs, you will always get the handle.

Answer (score 5):

That's because there was no error, delete did execute, it just didn't do anything. You want:

```
if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
  echo "done";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no error in your query.  It will complete successfully. If you read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) you will see:

"For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error."

As there is no error in your query it will return `TRUE` even though nothing has actually been deleted.  Deleting nothing is not considered an error.

Answer (score 0):

A delete query will always succeed, even if no rows are actually deleted.  If you want to determine how many rows were affected by an insert, update or delete operation, use `mysql_affected_rows()`